# Differential of $v\in L^p(\mu,X)\mapsto \frac1p\int_X |v(x)|^pd\mu(x)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space. I am trying to show that the differential of the function $F:v\in L^p(\mu,X)\mapsto \frac1p\int_X |v(x)|^pd\mu(x)$ is the function $g(v)=\begin{cases}|v|^{p-2}v&\text{ if }v\neq0\\0&\text{ if }v=0\end{cases}$. Should I compute the quantity $$\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{F(v+\epsilon w)-F(v)}{\epsilon}=\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to0}\frac1p\int_X \frac{|v(x)+\epsilon w(x)|^p-|v(x)|^p}{\epsilon}d\mu(x)?$$ How do I continue from here?

Comment: Dominated convergence

Comment: Sorry, I meant rather how to calculate the inside limit?

Comment: this is just the derivative of $x\mapsto |x|^p$...